# Difference between '.' and "." in java

Tags: java

Is there a difference between concatenating strings with '' and ""?

For example, what is the difference between:

```
String s = "hello" + "/" + "world";
```

and

```
String s = "hello" + '/' + "world";
```

Answer (score 27):

Literals enclosed in double quotes, e.g. `"foo"`, are **strings**, whereas single-quoted literals, e.g. `'c'`, are **chars**. In terms of concatenation behaviour, there'll be no discernible difference.

Nevertheless, it's worth remembering that strings and chars aren't interchangeable in all scenarios, and you can't have a single-quoted string made up of multiple characters.

Comment: To be pedantic, '\n' is an acceptable value for a char (although, strictly, that's just one char, even if represented as two).

Comment: *nod* - I was mainly trying to point out that the two kinds of quote aren't interchangeable as they are in many other languages.

Answer (score 13):

```
System.out.println('a'+'b'+'c');
> 294
System.out.println("a"+"b"+"c");
> abc
```

What's happening here is that (char)+(char)=(int)
In other words. Use "" for text to avoid surprises.

Answer (score 10):

`"."` is a String, `'.'` is a char.

Answer (score 4):

You may just look into the JDK :-)

Given two functions:

```
public static String concatString(String cs) {
    return "hello" + cs + "world";
}

public static String concatChar(char cc) {
    return "hello" + cc + "world";
}
```

after examination of the bytecode it boils down to two [AbstractStringBuilder.append(String)](http://kickjava.com/src/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java.htm#387) vs. [AbstractStringBuilder.append(char)](http://kickjava.com/src/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java.htm#572).

Both methods invoke [AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(int))](http://kickjava.com/src/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java.htm#92) which will allocate a new *char[]* eventually and *System.arraycopy* the old content first.

Afterwards [AbstractStringBuilder.append(char)](http://kickjava.com/src/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java.htm#572) just has to put the given char in the array whereas [AbstractStringBuilder.append(String)](http://kickjava.com/src/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java.htm#387) has to check a few constraints and calls [String.getChars(int, int, char[], int)](http://kickjava.com/src/java/lang/String.java.htm#716) which does another *System.arraycopy* of the appended string.

Answer (score 3):

"." is a String consisting of only one character.  '.' is a character.

Once you concatenate them together there is no difference.

Comment: There's a slight difference actually, it's marginally faster to append characters than single-character Strings. The difference is so minimal though that it really doesn't matter.

Comment: That's true.  But you could argue that telling a novice about this sort of minor issue may put them on the wrong path.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

'' is for character literals.

So you cannot do this:

"Osc" + 'ar' + "Reyes"

Because ar is not a character literal.

In your example it doesn't make much difference because

```
'/'
```

is a char literal, and

```
 "/"
```

is a String literal containing only one character.

Additionally you can use any UTF character with the following syntax

```
'\u3c00'
```

So you can also use:

```
"Osc" + '\u3c00' + "ar
```

Comment: One thing you have to remember is that the unicode it converted to the character before compiling. So '\u005c' will be converted to '\' which gives a compile-error.

Comment: @Peter: Ooohh!! I didn't knew this. Thanks for the comment: class Un { String s = "Osc" + '\u005c' + "ar"; }

Answer (score 2):

Adding a char is about 25% faster than adding a one character String.  Often this doesn't matter however, for example

```
String s = "hello" + "/" + "world";
```

This is converted to one String by the compiler so no String concatenation/append will occur at run-time in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it is quicker to add a char to a string - Java 6 seems to create StringBuffers under the covers and I remember reading on a Java Performance site that concatenating a char will be marginally quicker.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find the following articles useful:

- <s>[Java String Performance Testing](http://bitcraft.ca/2005/05/04/java-string-performance-testing/)</s>
- [Java String Concatenation](http://paulbarry.com/articles/2007/03/15/java-string-concatenation)

Answer (score 0):

char theLetterA = 'A';
string myString = "a string";

Answer (score 0):

you can only put a **single char** in between '' if you want to add **some more** characters use those in between "".

as string is a collection of characters like **strong text**"hello world"

we can have same thing by using '' like- **'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' .....**
and each has to be stored in different char variable which can be very hectic
so use "" when you have more than one char to store and '' for single char